# How does Unity Inspector handle values changing during play without any thread-locks?

Tags: unity, input, multithreading, ui-design, user-experience

First of all, I'm a `Java` coder. Usually, when you write a game, you run it on thread different than the `UI` one like:

```
// pseudocode starts
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
        while(someVolatileBoolean){
            input();
            physics();
            graphics();
        }
    }
}
```

and then you declare some sort of listener for the input which usually works on `application/UI thread` so you need to mark it as `volatile`, `atomic` or perform a basic synchro using the `synchronized` keyword (depending on the situation).

Let's take a simple `Unity` script:

```
public class SomeMovementScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 speed = new Vector3(0.1f, 0, 0);

    void Update () {
        this.transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

If we then play the game, the object starts to move with speed `0.1f`.

Now, when the game is playing, we can change the speed variable through the inspector:

[image]

I thought from the `UI` coder point of view: I'm changing a variable, which is being read each frame by the game thread. How does this happen, that I don't get some sort of `ConcurrentModificationException` if there's no visible synchronization at all. The variable is public, not being cached in any way.

I know that this question should be asked on `SO`, but I thought that `GD` has more users specialized in `Unity` and it's mechanics.

I came up with `immutability`. Variable is considered thread-safe if it's state can't change. As components are immutable, and classes like `Vector2/3/4` are immutable - it would work. But... You can make your own class `[Serializable]`, mark their fields as public and the class is not thread-safe - but it is visible through the inspector.

How does `Unity Inspector` perform these real-time updates with all the classes you can think of?

Comment: It is hard to tell "how exactly is Y implemented in X" (btw it is [considered offtopic](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/why-should-how-was-the-technique-in-x-done-be-considered-off-topic), explicitly named in [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), unless you study the source code. My bet though would be using same technique as UI frameworks do - the distapatcher pattern.

Comment: "Magic" is usually the answer when it comes down to "how does Unity do X?"